# why this call is not working?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I can interact with the smart contract but I can not read a avariable value .In this piece of code the withdrawToken() function is working but when I try to get the value of totalTokensSold variable in the contract I can not get the value (tokenForSale variable is declared in the js script):

```
T = async () => {
            a.value = !0;
            try {
                await n.value.methods.withdrawToken().send({
                    from: i.value
                }), p.success(`You have successfully unlock $${Ht.lockedToken.id} Tokens. Thank you!`), U()
            } catch {
                p.error("Signing failed, please try again!")
            }
            a.value = !1
    
       }, w = (O, N) => !+O || !+N ? 0 : Number.parseFloat(N) * Number.parseFloat(O), x = (O, N) => !+O || !+N ? 0 : Number.parseFloat(N) / Number.parseFloat(O),   
k = async () => {
const N=await n.value.methods.totalTokensSoldR().call(),
v.value = m.value.tokensForSale - N, v.value < 0 && (v.value = 0)};
```

If I set const N= 1000, it works and I get v.value correct.So why can I execute the withdrawToken function correctly and I'm not able to get totalTokensSoldR value ? I am able to read the variable in bscscan which is equal to 1000....

Comment: sorry the correct declaration is : const N=await n.value.methods.totalTokensSold().call();  but still not working....

Comment: The comma is an operator in javascript that returns the value of the last operation so here, check if that is the issue.